# Set specific values to zero in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have numpy array/matrix of shape `(4096,4096)` and an array of elements that should be set to zero. I have found function `numpy.in1d` that works fine but is very slow for my computations. I was wondering if exists some faster way for this execution because I need to repeat this on very large number of matrices so every optimization is helpful.

Here is example:

The numpy array looks like this:

```
npArr = np.array([
    [1, 4, 5, 5, 3],
    [2, 5, 6, 6, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [3, 3, 2, 4, 3]])
```

and another array is :

```
arr = np.array([3,5,8])
```

The numpy array `npArr` should look like after the replacement:

```
array([[ 1,  4,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  0,  6,  6,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  2,  4,  0]])
```

Comment: Your problem description is too vague. Give us an example with a small quadratic matrix and the expected result.

Comment: I am sorry for that. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, much better!

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: Sorry for late comment, your answer is great. Thank you once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
def in1d_alternative_2D(npArr, arr):
    idx = np.searchsorted(arr, npArr.ravel())
    idx[idx==len(arr)] = 0
    return arr[idx].reshape(npArr.shape) == npArr
```

It assumes `arr` to be sorted. If it's not, we need to sort and then use the posted method.

Sample run -

```
In [90]: npArr = np.array([[1, 4, 5, 5, 3],
    ...:     [2, 5, 6, 6, 1],
    ...:     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    ...:     [3, 3, 2, 14, 3]])
    ...: 
    ...: arr = np.array([3,5,8])
    ...: 

In [91]: in1d_alternative_2D(npArr, arr)
Out[91]: 
array([[False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [92]: npArr[in1d_alternative_2D(npArr, arr)] = 0

In [93]: npArr
Out[93]: 
array([[ 1,  4,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  0,  6,  6,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  2, 14,  0]])
```

**Benchmarking against `numpy.in1d`**

Equivalent solution using `np.in1d` would be :

```
np.in1d(npArr, arr).reshape(npArr.shape)
```

Let's time our proposed one against it and also verify results for the sizes mentioned in the question.

```
In [85]: # (4096, 4096) shaped 'npArr' and search array 'arr' of 1000 elems
    ...: npArr = np.random.randint(0,10000,(4096,4096))
    ...: arr = np.sort(np.random.choice(10000, 1000, replace=0 ))
    ...: 

In [86]: out1 = np.in1d(npArr, arr).reshape(npArr.shape)
    ...: out2 = in1d_alternative_2D(npArr, arr)
    ...: 

In [87]: np.allclose(out1, out2)
Out[87]: True

In [88]: %timeit np.in1d(npArr, arr).reshape(npArr.shape)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.04 s per loop

In [89]: %timeit in1d_alternative_2D(npArr, arr)
1 loops, best of 3: 1 s per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) you can solve this with a custom function that doesn't need an intermediate mask:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def replace_where(arr, needle, replace):
    arr = arr.ravel()
    needles = set(needle)
    for idx in range(arr.size):
        if arr[idx] in needles:
            arr[idx] = replace
```

This gives the correct result for your example:

```
npArr = np.array([[1, 4, 5, 5, 3],
                  [2, 5, 6, 6, 1],
                  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                  [3, 3, 2, 4, 3]])

arr = np.array([3,5,8])

replace_where(npArr, arr, 0)
print(npArr)
# array([[1, 4, 0, 0, 0],
#        [2, 0, 6, 6, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 2, 4, 0]])
```

And it should be really, really fast. I timed it for several array sizes and it was 5-20 times faster (depending on the sizes, especially the `arr` size) than `np.in1d`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using numpy broadcasting:

```
np.min(np.where(npArr[None,:,:] == arr[:,None,None], 0, a),0)
Out[730]: 
array([[1, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 6, 6, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 4, 0]])
```

Comment: You actually shouldn't try this with huge arrays because you create huge intermediate arrays. For an `npArr` of size `(4096,4096)` and `arr` of size 3 this creates a `3 * 4096 * 4096` array (50 million elements). And because you use `where` and the condition you actually have several of those huge arrays (I would guess 3 but I'm not sure). That can quickly exhaust the RAM.